# Use Laravel 5.3 Query Builder to replicate Eloquent ORM data structure for Sub Query

Tags: laravel

I am trying to replicate the result set that I get when using Eloquent ORM, except with Laravel Query Builder. Basically using this code I can get the packs to appear nested within the products so that when I loop them on the view I can further loop the packs within each products. Seems pretty basic right (see result set below).

```
        $get_posts_for_product = Product::where('active', 1)
                 ->with('packs')
                 ->get()->toArray();
```

[image]

I have tried a few ways using Query Builder to get this to work but it joins the packs inline as I thought it would.

What is the best way to get this same Array structure using Query Builder, I am aware that the result set is a different type of array and that is fine but for my project it must be done using Query Builder at this point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, that is why you have Eloquent: you don't have to worry about how to have those relationships together.

However incase you really want to achieve the same result I will demo this using two tables `users` and `messages`:

**1st method:**

Retrieve the users and transform it by querying the database for relationships:

```
$result = DB::table('users')->get()->transform(function ($user){
        $user->messages = DB::table('messages')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
        return $user;
});
```

> **Downside**: Having many users means a lot of db query on messages table.
>
> **Upside**: less codes to write

**2nd method:**

Retrieve both tables using all the ids of user to query the messages:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
$messages = DB::table('messages')->whereIn('user_id', $users->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();

$result = $users->transform(function ($user) use ($messages){
       $user->messages = $messages->where('user_id', $user->id)->values();
       return $user;
});
```

> **Downside**: The need to still transform it.
>
> **Upside**: Less database trips. i.e two queries only.

**3rd method**

Looks like the second except that you can group messages by 'user_id' then you do no extra filter when transforming `users` result:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->get();
$messages = DB::table('messages')->whereIn('user_id', $user->pluck('id')->toArray())
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('user_id');

$result = $user->transform(function ($user) use ($messages){
   $user->messages = $messages[$user->id];
   return $user;
});
```

> **Downside:** Same with two.
>
> **Upside:** no extra filter when transforming users.

**Other method**

Join on both users and messages when querying then transform the response, or simply use it as it is.

> PS: Eloquent uses query builder.
>
> The answer is open for update.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for your help.